# Can verbs become adjectives in sentences like "A _considered_ weakness for job A might actually be a strength for job B"?

Tags: adjectives, past-participles

This question is very important to me and I really want an answer. I am wondering whether verbs like the ones in the following examples can be adjectives and placed before nouns. Please tell me whether the ones with *As* are correct and if not, please mention the reason.

1. A weakness might be **considered** a weakness for job A, but considered  a strength for job B.

> 1A. A **considered** weakness for job A might actually be a strength for job B.

2. A topic that has been **explained** might still be in want of further explanation to  a layman.

> 2A. An **explained** topic might still be in want of further explanation to a
>   layman.

3. An area that has been **explored** extensively might still have unrevealed spots.

> 3A. An extensively **explored** area might still have unrevealed spots.

Answer (score 3):

In general, yes, you may employ both past and present participles as ordinary adjectives, and if they are not accompanied by their own following complements or modifiers they may be placed before the nouns they modify. Your #3/3a is an excellent example.

But I'm afraid your #1/1a won't work. It only **seems** to work because in #1 you have used the same word, *weakness*, for what are actually two different things: both the term modified and the complement of *consider*. Look at what happens if you change the first use:

> 1B. A trait might be considered a weakness for job A, but considered a strength for job B.
>   1C. A considered trait for job A might actually be a strength for job B.

Here #1C has obviously lost a key term. When an adjective or participle takes a following complement it must be placed *after* the noun it modifies:

> 1D. A trait considered a weakness for job A might actually be a strength for job B.

But if the adjective or participle takes a preceding modifier it may stand before the noun it modifies.

> 2B. A topic that has *already* been explained might still be in want of further explanation to a layman.
>   2C. An *already* explained topic might still be in want of further explanation to a layman.

Comment: Thank you Stoney for answering. So how about this one: "A trait widely known as a weakness might be a strength for a particular job."  To "A widely-known-as-a-weakness trait might be a strength for a particular job" Can I say this?

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom You could if you were trying to sound like a native speaker of German!

Comment: hahaha, why is that? I see many native English speakers put a lot of hyphenated words before a noun. Is it wrong or it just sounds odd?

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom It's doable, but only as a joke.